# Adding animate css to a flexslider caption

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animate.css

My knowledge of jquery is quite limited but basically when the `class=flex-active-slide` is added to the slide I wish to add `class=animate fadeInUp` to `class="caption-inner"`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.flex-active-slide .caption-inner').addClass('animate fadeInUp');});
```

end goal to make the animate css activate every time the slider changes

Comment: This code adds class when document is ready not after animating. You need to find where class flex-active is added and there add your class

Comment: https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/blob/master/jquery.flexslider.js#L154 looks like the jqeury creating that is on line 160

Comment: Use the [`before` or `after` callbacks](https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/blob/master/jquery.flexslider.js#L1141-L1147).

Comment: how would i go about doing that @AndréDion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i was able to get mine to work using the below code

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "fade",
    before: function(slider){
      $(slider).find(".flex-active-slide").find('.caption-inner').each(function(){
       $(this).removeClass("animated fadeInUp");
       });
     },
    after: function(slider){
          $(slider).find(".flex-active-slide").find('.caption-inner').addClass("animated fadeInUp");
      },

});
```

this should get you going

Answer (score 1):

Just add this to your CSS

```
.flexslider .flex-active-slide .animation.animated-item-1 {
-webkit-animation: fadeInDown 1500ms linear 1500ms both;
-moz-animation: fadeInDown 1500ms linear 1500ms both;
-o-animation: fadeInDown 1500ms linear 1500ms both;
-ms-animation: fadeInDown 1500ms linear 1500ms both;
animation: fadeInDown 1500ms linear 1500ms both;
}
```

You can of course make more variations. Give enough time for Flexslider to load the images first, hence the 1500ms.

In the HTML you add to the element (h1 or p)

```
class="animation animated-item-1"
```

And that's it! Enjoy, John

Answer (score 1):

Include animate.css and add the following style for flexslider's active-slide:

```
.flex-active-slide .flex-caption{
    animation-name:slideInUp; 
    animation-duration:1s;
    animation-fill-mode:both
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you instantiate your slider, use the [`after`](https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/blob/6df288146e89142dd770fa8eb0b11b055b98d473/jquery.flexslider.js#L1143) callback to apply your class:

```
$('.slider').flexslider({
    after: function(slider) {
        slider.slides.eq(slider.currentItem).find('.caption-inner').addClass('animate fadeInUp');
    }
});
```

Comment: this didn't work for me sadly flex slider is generating the current class as flex-active-slide. if that helps, i really need to figure out this stuff aha